# Debian 8 (Jessie) screen resolution issue

Tags: debian, gnome, resolution

I've upgraded a Toshiba Qosmio G30 laptop (Nvidia GeForce 7600 GPU) from Debian Wheezy to Jessie.

There is an issue with the screen resolution.

During boot the following messages are printed on the screen:

```
[ 14.784782] kvm: disabled by bios
[ 14.802038] kvm: disabled by bios
[16.668940] nouveau E[  VBIOS][0000:01:00.0] 0xda40[ ] : unknown opcode 0x00
[16.669004] nouveau E[  DEVINIT][0000:01:00.0] init failed, -22
[16.669004] nouveau E[  DRM] failed to create 0x80000080, -22
```

When the Gnome desktop opens the only resolutions offered are the default  1024x768 or 800x600.  The laptop screen is 1440x900.

I have tried creating and editing xorg.conf to suit the resolution but this results in a permanent black screen when the Gnome display manager tries to load.  I then reboot into rescue mode and 'rm' xorg.conf to recover the situation.

Is anyone able please to suggest how to get this installation working with the correct screen resolution?